# error with \MakeUppercase (arg 1) after update to ubuntu 23.10

Tags: pdftex, abntex2, texlive-2023

I'm facing an issue with a document that, in the previous version of Ubuntu (23.04), compiled without any errors. However, after updating to version 23.10, it's throwing a series of errors related to `! Paragraph ended before \MakeUppercase (arg 1) was complete.` and a few others, as visible in the image below. What's odd is that I don't have any \MakeUppercase in my file, and most errors seem to be associated with commented lines, which are not resolved by removing them.

I'm using pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) installed through texlive-full 2023.20230613-3. It seems the previous version, 2023.20230613-2, didn't have this issue. Does anyone know how I can revert to the previous version or fix this problem?

Many thanks!

[image]

Edit 1: I didn't show any code before because are basically commented lines, I'll show them and the beginning of the first chapter below:

```
%% abtex2-modelo-trabalho-academico.tex, v<VERSION> laurocesar
%% Copyright 2012-<COPYRIGHT_YEAR> by abnTeX2 group at http://www.abntex.net.br/ 
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%% 
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is the abnTeX2 team, led
%% by Lauro César Araujo. Further information are available on 
%% http://www.abntex.net.br/
%%
%% This work consists of the files abntex2-modelo-trabalho-academico.tex,
%% abntex2-modelo-include-comandos and abntex2-modelo-references.bib
%%

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% abnTeX2: Modelo de Trabalho Academico (tese de doutorado, dissertacao de
% mestrado e trabalhos monograficos em geral) em conformidade com 
% ABNT NBR 14724:2011: Informacao e documentacao - Trabalhos academicos -
% Apresentacao
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impressão mudar para twoside para facilitar impressaõ de frente e verso 
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    %chapter=TITLE,     % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %section=TITLE,     % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}

% ---
% Pacotes básicos 
% ---
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{color}              % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}          % para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

\usepackage{fmtcount} % equivalent to \usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}

% ---
        
% ---
% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo Canônico do abnteX2
% ---
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes de citações
% ---
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[num,overcite]{abntex2cite}
% --- 
% CONFIGURAÇÕES DE PACOTES
% --- 

% ---
% Configurações do pacote backref
% Usado sem a opção hyperpageref de backref
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
% Texto padrão antes do número das páginas
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
% Define os textos da citação
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
        Nenhuma citação no texto.%
    \or
        Citado na página #2.%
    \else
        Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
    \fi}%
% ---

% ---
% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
% ---
\titulo{title}
\autor{name}
\local{Belo Horizonte}
\data{2023}
\orientador{name}
\coorientador{name}
\instituicao{%
  Universidade Federal de Minas Gerais -- UFMG
  \par
  Departamento de Química
  \par
  Programa de Pós-Graduação}
\tipotrabalho{Tese (Doutorado)}
% O preambulo deve conter o tipo do trabalho, o objetivo, 
% o nome da instituição e a área de concentração 
\preambulo{Modelo canônico de trabalho monográfico acadêmico em conformidade com as normas ABNT apresentado à comunidade de usuários \LaTeX.}
% ---
```

My first chapter starts like this:

```
\chapter{Introdução} 

a lot of text ....
```

Comment: you have not shown any code so it is hard to help. the uppercase is probably in a chapter heading or page heading code, which needs updating, but hard to say with no example shown., The version of pdftex will not be an issue here, what matters is the version of latex, and of the class you are using, about which you have given no information.

Comment: OK, I showed more information but I don't know if it made a difference

Comment: you are not showing a failing example. That makes it quite difficult to debug. Try with ` \usepackage[nopatch=all]{microtype}`

Comment: when I used  the microtype package I received the error ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package microtype.

Comment: Sorry, but I only included the lines that triggered errors. My file has over 3500 lines, so I couldn't include everything.

Comment: you can make an example that shows the error, you don't have to include 3500 lines, you probably only have to include two or three lines, a chapter heading or a section heading or whatever it is causing the error. If you show no code people can not help. post a complete small document that shows the error. Probably @UlrikeFischer's suggestion will fix it, you will not get an option clash if you only load microtype once, if you are loading it twice, that is again in code you have not shown.

Comment: this has been fixed in `microtype` v3.1b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in the package update
abntex as reported and reproduced on [Github](https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/issues/259)

The solution is to either remove the microtype package or use \usepackage[nopatch=all]{microtype} as Ulrike Fischer first suggested in the comments.